# Differenza tra "fidati" e "conta su di me"

Tags: meaning, difference

Per quanto mi riguarda, le espressioni "fidati" e "conta su di me" hanno lo stesso significato.

Oppure c'è una differenza? In quali situazioni si usano e perché una utilizza il *riflessivo* mentre l'altra il *transitivo*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mio parere hanno due significati diversi.

Se dico "conta su di me" indico alla persona che sarò presente nel momento del bisogno, o  meglio che le presterò aiuto se necessario in una data circostanza. Lo tradurrei in inglese con "count on me". Ecco alcuni esempi:

> Conta su di me per la recita, sarò presente!

> Puoi contare su di me per andare a fare la spesa, ti accompagno in auto.

> Amico mio potrai sempre contare su di me.

> Vieni alla festa domani, ci conto!

Se "mi fido" di una persona, significa che penso che sia affidabile e che non mi tradirà, dandomi la possibilità di espormi ad esempio raccontandogli segreti. Può anche voler dire credere nelle capacità di qualcuno e perciò essere sicuri del fatto che non fallirà. Lo tradurrei in inglese con "trust". Ecco alcuni esempi:

> Non dirò a nessuno il tuo segreto fidati.

> Fidati riusciremo a vincere la partita, siamo una squadra formidabile.

> Non mi fido di te, ti conosco appena.

Utilizzerei "fidarsi" solo con persone che conosco davvero bene (infatti come dice il detto "fidarsi è bene non fidarsi è meglio"), mentre utilizzerei "conto su di te" anche semplicemente per esortare qualcuno con cui ho un accordo. Generalmente l'espressione "conto su di te" indica che ci si attende qualcosa di specifico dalla persona, mentre "mi fido di te" è più generale e assoluto.

Comment: Grazie tanto Alain

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Di nulla :)